# Monitor has stopped receiving input. Connected and registered but no display

Tags: multiple-monitors, lightdm, 18.10, xrandr

Overnight, my left side monitor doesn't display. It seems to be connected and registered with the display manager but no signal getting through.

I'm using lightdm as display manager now and have just upgraded to 18.10 from 18.04 hoping that would help. Still the same issue. I have tried the changing resolution but it either makes no difference of it says not found:

```
$ xrandr --output DP-2 --mode 1920x1080 --output DP-1 --mode 1920x1080 --same-as DP-2
xrandr: cannot find mode 1920x1080
```

Any ideas anyone?

xrandr output:

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 2944 x 1080, maximum 8192 x 8192
DP-1 connected 1024x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 531mm x 299mm
   1024x768      60.00* 
   800x600       75.00    60.32  
   720x576       50.00    50.00    50.00  
   720x480       60.00    60.00    59.94    59.94    59.94  
   640x480       75.00    72.81    66.67    60.00    59.94    59.94  
   720x400       70.08  
HDMI-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-2 connected primary 1920x1080+1024+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 531mm x 299mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+  60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1920x1080i    60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1680x1050     59.95  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1440x900      74.98    59.89  
   1280x720      60.00    60.00    50.00    50.00    59.94  
   1024x768      75.03    60.00  
   800x600       75.00    60.32  
   720x576       50.00    50.00    50.00  
   720x480       60.00    60.00    59.94    59.94    59.94  
   640x480       75.00    72.81    66.67    60.00    59.94    59.94  
   720x400       70.08  
HDMI-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

Comment: how did you perform the upgrade from 18.04 to 18.10? did you at any point uninstall/reinstall graphics driver? what graphics card do you have? are you using xorg or wayland, (if you don't know it's wayland)?

Comment: thanks for reply!  Graphics Card is: VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 630 (rev 04). I upgraded with standard upgrade-distro command. This has happened before several months ago but it sorted itself out some how and happen again now BEFORE upgrading, but the problem persists. Arandr does detect the monitor and have it as active, yet no signal is getting to the monitor. It's X11 ($ loginctl show-session c2 -p Type >>> Type=x11 )

Comment: no problem, you didn't answer my question about uninstalling graphics drivers. if you have intel graphics driver installed before upgrade you need to uninstall it and reinstall it. do you have this ppa: `ppa:oibaf/graphics-drivers` in your "Software and Sources" sources tab?

Comment: I have never manually installed a GC driver on this pc. I don't seem to have anything like that on my software / others -list of ppa and standard ubuntu repos

Comment: would you mind doing this then : `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:oibaf/graphics-drivers -y && sudo apt update && sudo apt full-upgrade -y`? then go into additional drivers see if it proposes anything, if yes, install it, and in both cases reboot.

Comment: done. Also rebooted. No additional drivers proposed.

Comment: Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 8192 x 8192
DP-1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 531mm x 299mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+  60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1920x1080i    60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1680x1050     59.95  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1440x900      74.98    59.89  
   1280x720      60.00    60.00    50.00    50.00    59.94  
   1024x768      75.03    60.00  
etc..

Comment: DP-2 connected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
   1024x768      60.00  
   800x600       75.00    60.32  
   720x576       50.00    50.00    50.00  
etc..   720x480       60.00    60.00    59.94    59.94    59.94  
   640x480       75.00    72.81    66.67    60.00    59.94    59.94  
   720x400       70.08

Comment: try logging out and logging back in switching to a xorg session. (use the gear cog)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91691/discussion-between-simon-p-and-tatsu).

Comment: good morning! just got your answer. it seems we have very differing times. I'm UTC+1